# Is it reasonable to use an external website as a health check

Tags: proxy, monitoring, load-balancing, network-monitoring

I have a 4 proxy servers spread across a couple of datacentres that serve a large number of users on a WAN. These are load balanced using an F5 GTM located at each site.

My goal is to write a health check for my load balancers that marks a proxy as down if either the proxy is down, or if it's local path to the internet is down. It seems to me that the most complete way for me to do this is to have my load balancer probe for an external URL through the proxy. Using my own web servers won't be a valid check because the connection won't need to leave the datacentre in order to pass the check. It feels unfair, even unethical to me to have my load balancers making requests to 3rd party URL's every few seconds all day every day to check the health of my proxy though.

My question is this: Would Google, for example, care if they were getting requests of this kind hitting their website constantly? Are there any better options, or any sites dedicated to being internet beacons?

Comment: If you are concerned about not disturbing too much other sites perhaps you can configure your tests to retrieve some local URL. But at this local URL have some CGI, php (your favorite ServerSide) with a huge lot of websites to check, but instead of checking all of them each time just pick randomly 2 of them; try to connect to them and if the result is OK print OK in your _test_ _page_.

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonable, but only if carefully arrangend. The choice of the wrong reference host can wreak havoc on your proxies: if you select a "unstable" reference host and it goes down, **all** you proxies will go down with it.

How to select a good reference host? Ideally, you want a remote host which itself has a redundant setup, so that chances it goes down are low.

The best thing would be to have **multiple** such hosts to verify and bring down your proxy if and only if *two or more reference hosts are down*

So, what hosts can you use? If very light on traffic (eg: a simple ping executed with 60 seconds cadence, or a simple HTTP GET) you can try to use some public 3rd party hosts as:

- google DSN (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) (PING)
- some international S/NTP servers (PING/NTP)
- some high volume traffic site (www.google.it / facebook.com / etc)

These are only some quick examples; if you have some servers on a different geographical location, you can use them as reference.